# How does local pass-the-hash (mimikatz's sekurlsa::pth) work?

Tags: authentication, windows, mimikatz, pass-the-hash

Mimikatz's [sekurlsa::pth documentation](https://github.com/gentilkiwi/mimikatz/wiki/module-%7E-sekurlsa#pth) states:

> mimikatz can perform the well-known operation 'Pass-The-Hash' to run a
> process under another credentials with NTLM hash of the user's
> password, instead of its real password.
>
> For this, it starts a process with a fake identity, then replaces fake
> information (NTLM hash of the fake password) with real information
> (NTLM hash of the real password).

What does this mean concretely? I'm under the impression that it doesn't simply authenticate as another user using the hash and then run a program (essentially runas with pass-the-hash), but does something a bit more involved.

This is also visible from event logs: when using any tool to do remote pth - e.g. CrackMapExec - this generates an event [4624](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624) with [logon type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4624#logon-types-and-descriptions) 3 (network logon) and standard characteristics, making it more or less indistinguishable from normal authentication. This is expected; it *shouldn't* be distinguishable from normal authentication.

However, when using `sekurlsa::pth`, the events generated are more peculiar: it's still event 4624; however, it comes with logon type 9 (*NewCredentials: A caller cloned its current token and specified new credentials for outbound connections. The new logon session has the same local identity, but uses different credentials for other network connections.*), which is pretty uncommon. If I understand this correctly, it means that the new logon session doesn't really *run a process under another credentials*; or rather, not on the *local* machine. Instead, it creates a session under the current user that can then be used to run processes *remotely* under the target user.

So, what does mimikatz's `sekurlsa::pth` do under the hood? And if my understanding is correct, what's the advantage over "regular" pass-the-hash?